# PHP variables remain blank after SQL fetch

Tags: php, html, mysqli, get

I am attempting to create an autofill info button that retrieves the last inserted information from MySQL and coupled with a $_GET autofills the page with the latest update. I am able to insert and update the data base just fine however upon retrieval of the information my variables remain empty.

I have verified the project-fill button is being posted. I also didnt get any error when checking the query's.

below is a snippet of the section that isnt working. It prints my header but the variables remain empty.

Apologies for sloppy code pretty green.

```
if(isset($_POST['project-fill'])) {
  require "dbh.inc.php";

//select the last inserted row the one with the highest id  
  $proj1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE id = MAX");
  $proj2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE id = MAX");
  $proj3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE id = MAX");

//select the column out of that row
  $result1 = mysqli_fetch_row($proj1['Project1']);
  $result2 = mysqli_fetch_row($proj2['Project2']);
  $result3 = mysqli_fetch_row($proj3['Project3']);

//transfer to project variable 
  $project1 = $result1;
  $project2 = $result2;
  $project3 = $result3;

//print header to allow for the $_GET method on the project page
  header (Location: ../update.php?update=sucessful&p1=".$project1."&p2=".$project2."&p3="$.project3);

}
```

Comment: I don't see you echoing anything. Plus, you don't need 3 queries. Also your [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is wrong.

Comment: I echo the variable on another pages form using the $_GET method to retrieve it from the header. Thats why i have the header script updating the header upon retrieving the information for each corresponding variable.

Comment: Don't change the question to match an answer. Then no one will understand the problems I was fixing in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to fetch a row from a result:

```
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_row($proj1['Project1']);
```

`$proj1` is a `mysqli_result` object, not an array, so you can't subscript it. You need to pass the object to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, and it returns an associative array with an element for each column.

```
$proj = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT Project1, Project2, Project3 
    FROM updates 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($proj);
$project1 = $row['Project1'];
$project2 = $row['Project2'];
$project3 = $row['Project3'];
```

You don't need to query 3 times to fetch different columns from the same row.

Comment: So ive correct the method of fetching a row from a result(mimicked displayed method) and unfortunately the header is still posting with blank values, as if the variable is returning blank and upon echoing this variable nothing is shown. I have successfully inserted values and verified that in my phpmyadmin. 

Is it required that this information is displayed in a table and unable to be echo'd to an input value inside a form?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check whether you're getting any warnings.